# How to multiply each row of a 3D matrix with each element of another 3D matrix on tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

I have two 3D tensors, tensor A with the dimension of `[32,1024,128]` and tensor B with the dimension of `[32,1024,1024]`, where 32 is the batch size. For a certain sample, I want to multiply each row of matrix A with each element of matrix B. So that the output tensor dimension will be `[32,1024,1024,128]`. I tried converting both tensors into 4D by using `tf.tile` and used elementwise multiplication. but it gives me out of memory error. I tried reducing the batch size into 4 but the same problem. Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem indeed needs a significant portion of memory. Here is a demonstration where I used 2 examples instead of all the examples in the `batch_size = 32`,

```
# input arrays to work with
In [2]: A = np.random.random_sample([32,1024,128])
In [3]: B = np.random.random_sample([32,1024,1024])

# inspect their memory usage

In [12]: A.nbytes/1000000
Out[12]: 33.554432   # ~ 33.5 Mb

In [13]: B.nbytes/1000000
Out[13]: 268.435456  # ~ 268 Mb

# your desired multiplication
In [14]: res = B[:2, ..., np.newaxis] * A[:2, :, np.newaxis, ...]

# desired shape of the output
In [15]: res.shape
Out[15]: (2, 1024, 1024, 128)

# inspect memory usage
In [16]: res.nbytes/1000000
Out[16]: 2147.483648  # ~ 2.1 GB
```

I used `float64` for these arrays. If you cannot afford such a memory requirement, one idea to lower the memory usage, thus avoiding the `Out Of Memory` errors, would be to downcast your arrays and use a single precision (i.e., `float32`) arrays.

---

Instead of tiling using `tf.tile` which actually creates a new tensor by copying the original tensor that many times, you could use [`tf.expand_dims`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims) which would be more performant in terms of memory.

These are the two lines of optimizations that I'd look into first.